# Implementing twitter-like timeline query based on datetime for an Event App

Tags: android, mysql, codeigniter, timeline

I am building an app for sharing events in android with codeigniter and mysql. What I'm trying to do is display a list of events in android app with limit, let's say only 10 result for each query, and later i can do a "load more" task.

If we talk about twitter timeline, let's say the status table has following columns (P.S. I made up these) :

- id (Consider this is the primary key with auto-increment)
- date_post
- tweet

If user post a tweet, the id automatically assigned with next auto increment value, and the datetime column assigned with current time, so the tweet is ordered properly, newer tweet will be inserted in larger id. With that, to display the timeline with limit 20 result each time loaded, and we load it from older tweet to the newer one, we can use the following query (CMIIW) :

```
SELECT * FROM TWEETS WHERE ID > last_id_loaded AND date_post >= last_date_loaded ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 20;
```

with the last_id_loaded is parameter we send based on the last tweet loaded or 0 if it's first time , same with the last_date_loaded parameter.

Now let's move back to my app. I have a table called events with the following column :

- id (primary key, auto increment)
- name (name of the event)
- date_start (datetime of which the event will held)
- etc

When a user create an event, the id will assigned with the next value of auto increment, but unlike the tweets table i mentioned before, the event is not ordered based on datetime, because larger id doesn't means newer event and vice versa. For example :

```
----- | ----------- | -------------
id    | name        | date_start
----- | ----------- | -------------
1       Event A       2013-05-26 13:13:00
2       Event B       2013-05-23 09:00:00
3       Event C       2013-05-27 10:00:00
4       Event D       2013-05-27 10:00:00
5       Event E       2013-05-27 10:00:00
6       Event F       2013-05-28 08:00:00
7       Event G       2013-05-31 13:13:00
8       Event H       2013-05-29 09:00:00
9       Event I       2013-05-29 08:00:00
10      Event J       2013-05-30 13:13:00
```

If we order based on the date_start column, it should be :
Event B, Event A, Event C, Event D, Event E, .... , Event G.

As we can see, there is 3 column with same date_start value : Event C, D, and E.
If I want to load event from older to newer one with limit only 3 for each query, which is i expect to return Event B, A, C, currently i use this following query :

```
SELECT * FROM EVENTS WHERE DATE_START >= last_date_retrieved ORDER BY DATE_START ASC, ID ASC
```

But then how can i make sure the next query will resulting the next value after that? I mean the previous query is resulting:
B, A, C with last date_start is 2013-05-27 10:00:00

If I use the previous query, it will resulting C, D, E, not D, E, and F like I expected.

What am i missing here?
I am ready to get some advices. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By far, i come up with these solution. I add new column in the event table called 'counter' which will be used as a counter for events  with the same datetime. For example, if we insert new event data, it will check the newly inserted event datetime with other. If same datetime exist in the table with max value 5, for example, the counter value for newly inserted event will be assigned with 5+1 = 6. I use a trigger for doing that

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `events_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
       SET @cnt = NULL;
       IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM events where date_start = new.date_start)  THEN 
           SELECT MAX(counter) into @cnt FROM events where date_start = new.date_start;
           SET new.counter = @cnt + 1;
       ELSE
           SET new.counter = 1;
       END IF;
    END;
```

I create a trigger too before update :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `events_BUPD` BEFORE UPDATE ON events FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @cnt = NULL;
IF old.date_start != new.date_start THEN 
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM events where date_start = new.date_start)  THEN
    SELECT MAX(counter) into @cnt FROM events where date_start = new.date_start;
    SET new.counter = @cnt + 1;
  ELSE
    SET new.counter = 1;
  END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

With that approach, i'll be able to query with these where clause :

```
WHERE (date_start = last_date_retrieved AND counter > last_counter_retrieved) 
OR (date_start > last_date_retrieved)
ORDER BY date_start, counter asc
```

Please let me know if any of you have a better approach on this. Thanks :)